# Finding mean of two arrays with dimensions (365,1) results in ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 365 to array axis with dimension 1

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays that pairs a GHI value to a date

```
resamples[0]
resamples[1]
print resamples[1]

            GHI
2917-01-01  553
2017-01-02  557
...         ...
2017-12-30  530
2017-12-31  313

[365 rows x 1 columns]
```

I am trying to find the means of each rows of the arrays by:

```
a = np.array([resamples[0],resamples[1]])
np.mean(a)
```

Which returns an error of:

```
a = np.array([resamples[0],resamples[1]])
ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 365 to array axis with dimension 1
```

I am new to Python and any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 2 to array axis with dimension 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18688565/valueerror-cannot-copy-sequence-with-size-2-to-array-axis-with-dimension-4)

Comment: Is this a pandas Dataframe? Then the obvious solutiion is to use [the built-in method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I am very clear with the exact requirement, but the following may help you.

Try replacing

```
a = np.array([resamples[0],resamples[1]])
np.mean(a)
```

with

```
np.mean(zip(resamples[0],resamples[1]),axis=1)
```

hope this helps